# Double question mark (??) help search not working in RStudio (and RStudio only)

Tags: r, rstudio

strange behaviour I noticed in my RStudio installation:

- Help search via the double question mark (e.g., `??gg`) does not work in RStudio. It gives me "No results found" in the Help pane.
- Help search via the upper search field in the Help pane works as intended and returns results for the example search above.
- `??` works in the Mac OS R GUI ("R.app"), it opens a browser tab with the results page.
- Single question mark `?` works also in RStudio (but of course only with exact matches to names).

Does anybody know how to resolve this? Thanks!

EDIT: My `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] jsonlite_1.6         scales_1.0.0         tidyr_0.8.3          ggplot2_3.2.0        koRpus.lang.de_0.1-1 koRpus_0.11-5       
[7] sylly_0.1-5          readxl_1.3.1         data.table_1.12.2   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       highr_0.8        cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.4.1     compiler_3.6.0   tools_3.6.0      zeallot_0.1.0   
 [8] digest_0.6.19    tibble_2.1.3     gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.4.0      cli_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.10 
[15] curl_3.3         yaml_2.2.0       xfun_0.8         knitr_1.23       withr_2.1.2      dplyr_0.8.1      vctrs_0.1.0     
[22] grid_3.6.0       tidyselect_0.2.5 sylly.de_0.1-2   glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.0         fansi_0.4.0      purrr_0.3.2     
[29] magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.4  fortunes_1.5-4   assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 labeling_0.3     utf8_1.1.4      
[36] lazyeval_0.2.2   munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue that should be fixed in the [preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) of RStudio.

Comment: It is, indeed! Thank you.